# How to find length of $\overline{CE}$

Tags: geometry

[image: triangles_with_shared_side]

As you can see, $$AD\cap BC = {E}$$ $$AD\bot BC$$ $$ AB = BD = 6$$ $$AC = BC = 9$$ $$CE = x$$
How do I find $x$? I need help at this question. Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Pythagorean Theorem,
$$AE^2 + BE^2 = AB^2$$
and 
$$AE^2 + CE^2 = AC^2$$
Subtracting the first equation from the second yields 
$$CE^2 - BE^2 = AC^2 - AB^2$$ 
Since $AC = 9$, $BE = 9 - x$.  Substituting $9$ for $AC$, $6$ for $AB$, $x$ for CE, and $9 - x$ for $BE$ yields 
$$x^2 - (9 - x)^2 = 81 - 36$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be the midpoint of $AB$. Then $\triangle BMC \sim \triangle BEA$ with ratio $3:2$ as they share $\angle ABC\neq90°$ and are right-angled.

Hence $BM:BE = 3:2\implies BE=2\implies CE = BC-BE=9-2=7$